# OpenCV cornerSubPix Exception

Tags: .net, opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am attempting to calibrate a Logitech c930 camera and keep getting an exception when I follow what I think is the sample calibration code.

I am using OpenCV 2.4.9 with VS2012 c++/cli on a Win 8.1 machine. I have attempted to follow the tutorial code at:
`C:\opencv\sources\samples\cpp\tutorial_code\calib3d\camera_calibration\camera_calibration.cpp`.

My code looks like:

```
while(successes<CALIBRATE_NUMBER_OF_BOARDS_TO_MATCH && totalframes<CALIBRATE_TOTAL_FRAMES)
{
    // check for new image
    if(CameraVI->isFrameNew(CameraNumber))
    {
        vector<Point2f> pointBuf;
        TermCriteria criteria = TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1 );

        totalframes++;

        // load the image from the buffer
        CameraVI->getPixels(CameraNumber, LdataBuffer, false, true);

        // convert it to a mat
        cv::Mat tImage(Images->Height, Images->Width, CV_8UC3, LdataBuffer, Mat::AUTO_STEP);

        bool found = findChessboardCorners(tImage, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK| CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

        if(found)
        {
            successes++;
            cvtColor(tImage,grayImage,CV_BGR2GRAY);
            cornerSubPix( grayImage, pointBuf, Size(11,11), Size(-1,-1), criteria);
            imagePoints.push_back(pointBuf);
        }

        drawChessboardCorners( tImage, board_sz, Mat(pointBuf), found );
    }
    Sleep(35);
}
```

When I run this, I consistently get an exception on the cornerSubPix call. I know that the image coming in is correct (it is 1920 x 1080) as I can show the image to the screen. Also, the pointBuf seems to be correctly defined and I can access it before the cornerSubPix call. One thing I do notice is that some examples use CV_BGR2GRAY for the color conversion while others use CV_RGB2GRAY. I have tried both but still get the exception. Some examples also use a 5x5 instead of an 11x11 window. I have also tried both but still get the exception.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: "External component as thrown an exception."

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and it was stupid.  I was storing the point found by findChessboardCorners in one vector (corners) but using a different vector (pointBuf) for the cornerSubPix call.  cornerSubPix apparently does not like an empty vector.  Not sure why my try/catch call did not report this.